# Uploading of projects and theses

Tags: publications, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, online-publication

I’m an undergraduate currently working on a project with my supervisor. As far as I know, my supervisor is generally reluctant to publish (that includes the university database). I suspect this will also be the case for the project I’m working on. Is it legal if I upload the final version on say ResearchGate? I want to communicate with others about what I have done and since it is likely that my Bachelor’s thesis will be done under said supervisor, I would like to know what options I have. I can only think of describing the project/thesis in detail as an alternative if I want to list said project/thesis.

Comment: Why is he reluctant to publish? Does he have very high standards?

Comment: I don’t really know, just his personal preference I guess. He’s on the teaching track so he probably doesn’t need to publish, if at all.

Comment: It's unwise to go against the lecturer, but if it's good work, perhaps you can convince him?

Comment: *He’s on the teaching track* --- My experience is that those primarily involved in teaching like to display their student projects as motivation/reward for students, guides for future students doing projects, and "advertisement" for the teacher's teaching/scholarship activities. In fact, I was teaching (among other things) a differential equations course each year in the late 1990s and there was a teacher who had student projects on the internet that I had my students look at, and interestingly enough [those projects](https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/DEproj/index.php) are still online!

Answer (score 1):

None of this would be illegal, at all likelyhood (but I am not a laywer).

The more important question is whether it is ethical or not.

With regard to theses (i.e., bachelor, master thesis, also PhD thesis), I don't see any issue in posting the thesis somewhere public. (Indeed, PhD thesis usually *must* be published.) After all, your thesis is *your* work (certainly this is the formal point of view), and it is up to you what you do with your work.

On the other hand, if you have a supervisor who wants to publish results from the thesis as part of a journal article, it might be better not not publish the thesis before that, such as to protect your ideas until the paper is out. However, this is more about being smart than about being ethical. Also, as far as I see there is no such issue involved here.

Note that the situation is different for results which are not part of the thesis, and which is not solely your work: In that case, you cannot publish them without consent of your coauthors. (Again, this is not about being illegal, but about research and publication ethics.)

Finally, even if it is fine to post your thesis, a bachelor thesis in practice often *does* involve contributions from the supervisor, so it is probably smart to ask them for permission. As has been pointed out, they might well be happy to showcase good students.  And last, since your supervisor does not seem to care much about publishing, they should not mind those ideas being publicly available (unlike when they would like to use towards for a publication).

Comment: An exception is if the advisor is a proper co-author of the work or is (or needs to be) otherwise mentioned in such a way that requires his permission to use his name.

Comment: @Buffy I am talking primarily of theses here - this is what the question seems mostly about. On a formal level, I don't think the advisor can be a co-author of the thesis in any way, even though there might be regional differences.  (In practice, this is of course different, see the last paragraph.)  So I don't think there would be a formal issue with posting the thesis, and it is (by construction) your work.

Comment: Sorry, but pretty common in some fields.

Comment: @Buffy ?? ________